# Joomla 2.5 xml fields - store values after form submit

Tags: php, joomla

I have a typical XML file with many field like example

```
<field
type="custom"
name="city"
id="city"
label="City"
size="40"/>
```

In the view I display this field - everything is fine.
Moreover I'm using state filtering on this field.
model populateState():

```
$filter = $app->input->get('city');
$this->setState('filter.city', $filter);
```

The problem is that, field doesn't has a value after form submit (form has `get` method). I can't write in field `value` something like `$this->getState('city')` because it's xml file. Maybe anyone has a solution... I was thinking about JS, but mainly I want to have a PHP solution.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!
Here is solution:
1. Have all fields name in jform array. It makes automatically if you use form in xml.
2. When you're loading form data, send second parameter as true: `$model->getForm('formName', true)` because second parameter is `$loadData`. By this option, Joomla will load form data.
3. You have load data from `loadFormData` function:

```
protected function loadFormData() {
        $data = JFactory::getApplication()->getUserStateFromRequest('jform', 'jform');
        if (empty($data)) {
            $data = $this->getItem();
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking, but if you're using a standard JForm and inserting it with something like this:

```
echo $this->form->getInput('articletext');
```

The it's likely the your field's name in the form isn't `city`, it's more likely to be something like:

```
`jform[articletext]`
```

If you can add more of the XML file, so we can see grouping etc and the `php` used to display the form we can probably help pin it down exactly, it will also help if you tell us which version of Joomla you're using.

Comment: I've make a mistake in post. This field has `type="custom"`, so `$app->input->get('miasto');` is right. I'll try to describe problem one time yet. I'm creating form by xml like in a example. When I submit form, I want to store in fields sent values. For example, I have url: `index.php?someting=sample` - it means field `name="someting"` have to have filled `value` with `sample`. Joomla 2.5